# Where are the API docs for SmartPy?

Tags: smart-contracts, smartpy

I'm working on a contract now and specifically I'd like to call a SmartPy API like `sp.transfer(address, amount)`? Is there a function like this?

I can't find API docs for SmartPy and digging into the SmartPy module didn't get me very far.

Where should I be looking for more info?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is this: sp.send(sp.address("tz1"), sp.tez(420))

I can't find much documentation for sp.send but I have seen many SmartPy examples with sp.send and sp.amount

Answer (score 1):

SmartPy is still early stage and under development with new features being added regularly. The main links to documentation can be found on their website https://smartpy.io/ -- these all mostly point to the various medium articles that describe the components that make up the SmartPy language and tools. The best resources for how to use SmartPy to develop contracts are the examples found in the medium articles.

Additionally, the online editor has some of the basics documented at https://smartpy.io/demo/smartpy_help.html

Comment: Thank you and understood. Regarding `transfer()` specifically, does it exist? Where is it? I dig into the smartpy module and find only `from .smart import SMART
from . import objfunctions
from .version import __version__`. I dig further into those and can't find this method.

Thanks!

Comment: That sounds like a different question. Stackexchange works best when you ask a very specific question with as much detail as possible I suggest you ask how to transfer using smartpy with all the details of exactly what it is you are trying to accomplish. That way it is easy for someone very familiar with that area of smartpy to find and answer your question. The question was specifically about where to get the docs, please add a new question.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. I've seen them as well, yet hadn't seen an example transferring money.

Comment: My first sentence was my actual question. I provided a sample code call of what I wanted to do. The second question about docs was only because I was looking for an answer to my first question.